# Cannot delete redundant partitions

Tags: partition

I finally decided to replace Windows Vista by Ubuntu. I needed several attempts as I am not experienced with disk partitions. I want to have only one partition with ubuntu installed there. I managed to install ubuntu. However, I have three partitions instead of only one, please look at the picture.

[image]

I want to delete two redundant partitions so that only one remains.

Details on the partitions:

1. Partition type: Linux (Bootable); Contents: Ext4 (version 1.0) — Mounted at Filesystem Root
2. Partition type: Extended; Contents: Extended Partition
3. Partition type: Linux swap; Contents: Swap (version 1) — Active

I guess that I can keep only the first partition and delete the others. However, when I try to delete one of those two partitions, I receive the following error message:

> Error deleting partition: Error deleting partition /dev/sda2:
>   Command-line `parted --script "/dev/sda" "rm 2"' exited with non-zero
>   exit status 1: Warning: Partition /dev/sda2 is being used. Are you
>   sure you want to continue?  (udisks-error-quark, 0)

What can I do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The swap partition is the traditional way in Linux of handling what in Windows is called "virtual memory". That is, when you run out of RAM (among other situations; other examples of things that use swap include hibernating the system (suspend to disk)), the swap partition will be used as an "overflow" for things that won't fit in RAM (which of course will be slower but means your system can keep running rather than having to crash or kill processes seemingly at random).

So, the simple answer is that you don't need to delete this partition; it's a normal part of Ubuntu.

The "extended partition" can be seen as a "container" for additional partitions. Because it's a very old format dating from the IBM PC/MS-DOS days, the partition table used on modern computers only allows four partitions by default. In order to let you have more than this, systems will create an "extended partition" which is just another (more powerful) partition table stored in place of a partition, effectively giving you the ability to create any number of partitions rather than just four.

(If you really positively do want to delete it, which I don't recommend at all, you can stop the system from using it by typing "sudo swapoff /dev/sda3" at a terminal before deleting it.)

Comment: Ok, thank you for the clarification. I wondered why the partition is named "Linux swap". Do have any idea about the second partition?

Comment: I've just edited my answer, as I realised I didn't mention it. It's a bit more complicated to explain, it's basically a container for more partitions.

Comment: Thanks. I will certainly keep the "Linux swap" partition. But I don't think I will ever need more than four partitions, so is there any way to delete the "extended partition"? Or is there any good reason to keep it anyway?

Comment: To delete it you'd have to first delete the swap partition, then recreate it afterwards. It's possible, but it'll literally only save 512 BYTES of space (correct me if I'm wrong, someone), and so really, given the size of modern hard drives, it's causing no harm by being there.

Comment: Well, the size of the extended partition is 4,3 GB. If I can somehow resolve this issue by reinstalling ubuntu for example, then I have no problem with that (as I have a fresh install anyway). But I am not sure if that would help.

Comment: The extended partition is 4.3GB because it "contains" the swap partition which is also 4.3GB. It'll only take up one lot of 4.3GB on your disk, that's why they're shown one above the other on the diagram (not the most obvious thing I know!) :)

Comment: On "up to 7 in total" ... MBR partitioning provides up to four primary partitions, or up to three primaries and one extended. An MBR extended partition can *theoretically* contain any number of logical partitions.

Comment: Muzer, thank you very much, you have been very helpful (and fast)!

Comment: Ah, thanks Christopher, I stand corrected - I will edit my answer!

Comment: So is it standard to have all these partitions after installing ubuntu? I previously thought that I somehow messed the installation up.

Comment: Yes, it's standard. I know that ages ago they didn't create the extended partition, but I think they probably changed that because if you have an existing Windows installation, a recovery partition, and then the two partitions Ubuntu creates, you would already have run out of space in your partition table if you wanted any more! It probably just creates it in all cases where it doesn't exist already so it doesn't have to bother asking the user a question they likely can't answer, even though it doesn't make much sense in this scenario!